# Merge from remote

Tags: git, tortoisegit

When doing a merge from remote TortoiseGit doesn't check if version is up-to-date, so, every time I try to merge I have to fetch first and only then I can merge a remote in, otherwise it will (erroneously) say that remote is up-to-date.

Is there an easy way, that every time I attempt a merge from remote, TortoiseGit does a fetch first?

Comment: In Git, **fetch** + **merge** = **pull**.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I want to merge a dev branch into my working branch

Comment: Well then you should either *pull* into that branch first or you have to fetch first if you're merging the remote-tracking branch. That's how Git does it, and I imagine TortoiseGit is no different.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I'm working on my local branch-A. I want to merge remote dev branch-B into this branch. I *have* to first fetch or pull branch-B to be able to merge it into local branch-A, otherwise for all my local knows, branch-B is up-to-date even though it's a remote and is not updated. I'd like TortoiseGit to do that for me. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: When pulling you can explicitly specify another branch name you want to fetch and merge.

Comment: @MrTux Yes. You can do that - I was expecting that TortoiseGit might not provide that option.

Comment: @MrTux can you please put this as answer? I can't see it in the options for pull or merge and all I want is to forget about fetching when doing a merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fetch + merge = pull

When pulling you can explicitly specify another branch name you want to fetch and merge.

Just enter the branch on the remote you want to merge into "Remote Branch" - same applies to the Sync Dialog.

[image: Pull Dialog]

Comment: Thank you very much - I was accustomed to doing merge via merge (hence the question) where it plainly doesn't check the remote.